# How can I give more weight to some outputs over others in a neural net?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Say I have a neural net with 5 outputs:

```
[o1, o2, o3, o4, o5]
```

How can I give more weight to `o5`? So that when calculating the cost function, `o5` will have a larger effect than any of the other outputs.

For example, say the error of `o1` is 0.1 and the error of `o5` is 0.1. The error of `o5` should have a bigger effect on the cost function than the error of `o1`.

Specifically, I'm looking to do this in tensorfow/keras.

---

Another more detailed example:

`[o1, o2, o3, o4]` are all values between 0 and 1 and are representative of several deviations from an average housing price.

`o5` is a value between 0 and 1 and is representative of the urgency of the sellers of the homes; Whether they are desperate to sell or not desperate to sell.

Slight inaccuracies in o1, o2, o3, o4 are **not** as important as inaccuracies in o5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `model.compile()` there is an optional parameter `loss_weights`. Below is a description of the parameter from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile):

> Optional list or dictionary specifying scalar coefficients (Python floats)
> to weight the loss contributions of different model outputs.
> The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the
> weighted sum of all individual losses, weighted by the `loss_weights`
> coefficients. If a list, it is expected to have a 1:1 mapping to the
> model's outputs. If a dict, it is expected to map output names
> (strings) to scalar coefficients.

so in your case you need to create a dictionary as follows

```
loss_weights{'o1':1.0
             'o2':1.0
             'o3':1.0
             'o4':1.0
             'o5':5.0}
```

In the dictionary above o5 carries 5 times the impact on the loss function than the other outputs. Set these values as needed to match the importance of each output.
Note in model.compile set `loss_weights=loss_weights`

Answer (score 1):

Use `loss_weights` argument of `compile()`. See here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile.